# How to add timestamp indexes to a dataframe at minute intervals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I hae a dataframe with timestamp as index. i want to add more rows to the beginning and the end of the dataset at minute intervals. eg. if the data set starts at 6: 00 am, I want entries from 5 00 am to 6 00 am at the start of the dataset for every minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set your index you should be able to pass in the parameter freq=‘T’ along with the range of timestamps that you require.

More detail:
With your index set to your datetime you can build an index per minute on your desired datetime range

```
start = pd.datetime(2019, 5, 7, 5)
end = pd.datetime(2019, 5, 7, 6)
myIndex = pd.date_range(start, end, freq=‘T’)
df.reindex(myIndex)
```